# Implicit function theorem \ Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus

Given $p,q>0$ so that $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$.

I need to prove that for all $a,b > 0$: $\frac{b^q}{q}+\frac{a^p}{p}\ge ab$

I think that this question is related to maxima and minima, and therefore I need to use lagrange multipliers, or the implicit function theorem, but I really don't know where do I begin from :(

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Consider the area of rectangle with side lengths a and b, on the other hand, the area of shape under the curve $y=x^{q-1}, x\in[0,b]$ and $x=y^{p-1}, y\in[0,a]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a version of Young's inequality.  One way is to use the fact that log function is concave.

So $\log\left(\dfrac{b^q}{q}+\dfrac{a^p}{p}\right) \ge \dfrac{\log(b^q)}{q} + \dfrac{\log(a^p)}{p} $.  Here we have used that the weights sum to $1$ and concavity.

So $\log(\frac{b^q}{q}+\frac{a^p}{p}) \ge \log(b) + \log(a) = \log(ab)$. Taking exponents, we have the inequality you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For each fixed $b$ find the minimum value of $f(a)=\frac{b^q}{q}+\frac{a^p}{p}-ab$.

> $f'(a) = 0$ implies $a=b^{q-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\mbox{Set}\quad {1 \over q} \equiv \cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)\,,
\quad
{1 \over p} \equiv \sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)\,;\qquad 0\ <\ \theta\ <\ {\pi \over 2}
$$

and you get a function of one variable $\left(~\theta~\right)$.